# Creating new object in routes.php in slim

Tags: php, slim

I want to create new object in routes.php using slim framework. Example 
User Mapper.

```
 **Routes.php**

 $app->get('/login', function($request,$response,$args){  
    $user = new UserMapper($this->db);
    });
```

I have created db connection in dependencies.php
But I am getting error UserMapper not found. If i am including UserMapper class in routes.php then server error occurs.

Comment: How do you autoload your classes? Also, if server error occurs, check the code in `UserMapper` class, it's likely there's a typo.

Comment: Thanks Georgy !! It was typo error.